# Can an Azure Machine Learning Compute Instance shut down itself automatically with a bash script executed by crontab?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a compute instance that starts at 12:00 with the scheduler of Azure ML and does a job scheduled in the crontab of the CI at 12:10. The thing is that this job doesn't always takes the same time to finish. So i want the CI to shut down itself when done.

The script that the crontab executes is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
#!/bin/bash

...

# CRREATE FOLDER FOR LOGS
foldername=$PROJECT_PATH/$(date '+%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')
mkdir $foldername

filename=az_login.txt
path=$foldername/$filename
touch $path
az login -u *<USERNAME>* -p *<PASSWORD>* > $path


filename=acr_login.txt
path=$foldername/$filename
touch $path
# Authenticate to ACR
az acr login --name $ACR_NAME > $path

filename=pull_container.txt
path=$foldername/$filename
touch $path
# Pull the container image from ACR
docker pull $ACR_NAME.azurecr.io/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG > $path


filename=run.txt
path=$foldername/$filename
touch $path
# Run the container image
docker run -v $CREDENTIALS_PATH:/app/config_privilegies $ACR_NAME.azurecr.io/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG > $path

filename=rm_container.txt
path=$foldername/$filename
touch $path
# Delete the exited containers
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q --filter "status=exited") > $path


az ml compute stop --name *<CI_NAME>* --resource-group *<RESOURCE_NAME>* --workspace-name *<WORKSPACE_NAME>* --subscription *<SUBSCRIPTION_NAME>*
```

---

Everything works great until the stop command. In this particular code, it does nothing.
I've tried to put the last command in a seperate bash script and changing the last line for "./close_ci.sh". However, this doesn't work either, it restarts the CI instead of stopping it.

Answer (score 0):

az ml compute stop --name <CI_NAME> --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> --workspace-name <WORKSPACE_NAME> --subscription <SUBSCRIPTION_NAME> &

you can try to run the script in a separate shell script and run the shell script in the crontab.